# The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Tamode, int, List<String>) is undefined

Tags: android

I'm using the array adapter for drop down menu in class extending fragment. Below is code of arrayadapter. It shows constructor undefined.
Please help me out to solve this.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> da=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                 list1);
da.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
s1.setAdapter(da);
```

Comment: `Tamode` extending Activity or Fragment?

Comment: is your 'this' refers to context ?, check if it matches to constructor defined in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int%29

Comment: Tamode is name of activity.

Answer (score 0):

I hope Tamode is the name of your activity, `ArrayAdapter` is having the following constructors available, please read the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int%29), the first argument should be Context, so instead if `Tamode`, you have to use `Tamode.this`, that will work

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".Tamode"
                       android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.electrofantacy.RESIST" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: This is my manifest code for defining Tamode activity. Anything wrong in this?

Comment: seem like there is no issue in manifest, and the error is not an issue about manifest